# How do I enable Reader mode on Chrome on my Mac without downloading an extension?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web-browser

I want to remove all advertisements and just see the text of the articles I'm reading.

Comment: Are you looking for a plug in to modify the chrome browser? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reader-view/iibolhpkjjmoepndefdmdlmbpfhlgjpl

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a way to do this without using an extension/plugin. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/90973/143839

Comment: I'm seeing a downvote and vote to close on this question. I wasn't positive it made sense to post on this stack site, would be curious where it could be a better fit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. "[Enable](http://chrome://flags/#enable-reader-mode) Reader Mode" within Chrome Experiments
2. Relaunch Chrome
3. Navigate to an article, open "View" in the Chrome menu bar, and select "Reader mode"
4. **Optional**: Create a keyboard shortcut in "Keyboard" settings in "System Preferences", "App Shortcuts", "Google Chrome", "Reader mode" (example key binding: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>)